# Downloading torrent contents with ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, torrent

I am fairly new to web development and I have been looking for a way to download torrent-files using ASP.NET C#.

It would work like this:

1. User uploads a torrent file or magnet link to the website.
2. The website downloads the torrent contents into a folder on the web server.

I came across something called: 'mono-torrent' for C#, but apparently this does not work with ASP.NET. I know Node.JS has something called 'node-torrent'... so it should be possible with C#, right?

If someone can please help me out or point me into a general direction on how to achieve this... I have been looking everywhere on the internet on how to do this with ASP.NET. I do not have access to RDP (Remote Desktop Services) unfortunately.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: show what you have tried so far ;)

Comment: I can't show anything if I can't find anywhere on the internet on how to go about doing this.

Answer (score 1):

What do you mean by "does not work with ASP.NET"? Apart from the fact it's pretty old and complicated code, it should be working in any .NET application. However, [Leak](https://github.com/amacal/leak) may be a viable alternative since it seems to be developed actively and has decent documentation.

It should be noted, since downloading torrent is usually a long-running task, you'll need some extra thinking ([1](https://stackoverflow.com/q/536681/55209),[2](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4322126/55209),[3](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24115642/55209) etc.) to offload jobs to background thread and persist them between application restarts.

Answer (score 0):

You can download torrent files using ASP.NET C# by using a library called **MonoTorrent**. However, it is pretty old and complicated code ¹. Another alternative is **Leak**, which is actively developed and has decent documentation ¹. Here is a general direction on how to achieve this:

1. User uploads a torrent file or magnet link to the website.
2. The website downloads the torrent contents into a folder on the web server.

Since downloading a torrent is usually a long-running task, you'll need some extra thinking to offload jobs to background thread and persist them between application restarts ¹.